# Issue converting Pascal Case Json payload to Camel Case payload

Tags: c#, json

Is it recommended or even possible to convert Pascal Case JSON string to Camel Case JSON?

I know how to deserialize the payload to an object and then serialize it to a string again but that is not what I want at the moment.

So far I have done this:

```
JsonSerializerOptions jsonOptions = new() { PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase};
var pascalPayload = "{\"Id\":\"1\",\"Type\":\"Confectionary\"}";
var camelCasePayload = JsonSerializer.Serialize(pascalPayload, jsonOptions)
```

The issue I see here is that it contains the following characters and I wasn't expecting that and also my properties are not serialized to camelcase.
For example

```
 {\u0022Id:\u00221\u0022,....
```

Am I missing something from the serialisation options because I was expecting this as the output:

```
"{"id":"1","type":"Confectionary"}";
```

Comment: You are serializing a string and not an object.... Serialize expects an object... In your case you are passings a string.

Comment: you are trying to serialize something that's already serialized. you will have to deserialize to object and then serialize back out. Or else you're looking at string manipulation, which likely would be more error prone.

Comment: @Jonathan I was looking if it is possible to convert the already serialized Pascal JSON string to CamelCase JSON string. How easy is it that using the libraries available?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a string to Serialize and not an object.  So you are effectively serializing a string which already is json into a string value....

You need to pass an object like this:

First declare a class:

```
public class MyPayload
{
     public string Id { get; set; }
     public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Then your code:

```
JsonSerializerOptions jsonOptions = new() { PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase};
//notice we create an instance and pass that to Serialize
var pascalPayload = new MyPayload { Id = "1", Type = "Confectionary"};
var camelCasePayload = JsonSerializer.Serialize(pascalPayload, jsonOptions);
```

There is no way around it using JsonSerializer.... If you dont want to use an object then you need to manipulate the string yourself.

Comment: So are you saying I must have a class to deserialize to? I essentially wanted to convert the PascalCase JSON string to CamelCase JSON string without having to declare a class.

Comment: You could probably deserialize as an anonymous type and then re-serialize *that*. Then you wouldn't have to build hard-coded classes.

Comment: @Jonathan that is true nevertheless the principle is the same... he has to serialize then deserialize an object.  In the case of an anonymous type... well it is also hardcoded.